# Test a chained call of methods having lambda parameters with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I've got the following interfaces:

DAOFunctionCommand:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface DAOFunctionCommand<T, R>
{
    R execute(T input, IDAOManager manager) throws Exception;
}
```

DAOSupplierCommand:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface DAOSupplierCommand<T>
{
    T get(IDAOManager manager) throws Exception;
}
```

ITransactionStream:

```
public interface ITransactionStream<T, K extends IDAOManager>
{
    <R> ITransactionStream<R, K> chain(DAOFunctionCommand<? super T, ? extends R> cmd) throws Exception;

    <R> ITransactionStream<R, K> chain(DAOSupplierCommand<? extends R> cmd) throws Exception;

    T getResult();

    T end() throws Exception;
}
```

ITransactionHead:

```
public interface ITransactionHead<T, K extends IDAOManager>
{
    ITransactionStream<T, K> start() throws Exception;
}
```

IDAOManager:

```
public interface IDAOManager
{
    ITicketDAO getTicketDAO() throws Exception;

    IParkingSpotsDAO getParkingSpotDAO() throws Exception;

    IParkingSpotCategoriesDAO getParkingSpotCategoriesDAO() throws Exception;

    ITransactionHead<Object, ? extends IDAOManager> txStream() throws Exception;
}
```

Somewhere in the code an IDAOManager is used like this:

```
public Optional<ParkingSpot> occupySpot(String category) throws Exception
{
    daoManager.getParkingSpotCategoriesDAO().get(category);

    Optional<ParkingSpot> ps = daoManager.txStream()
            .start()
            .chain((m) -> m.getParkingSpotDAO().getFreeSpot(category))
            .chain((p, m) ->
            {
                if (!p.isPresent()) return Optional.<ParkingSpot>empty();
                p.get().setAvailable(false);
                m.getParkingSpotDAO().update(p.get());
                return p;
            }).end();

    if (ps.isPresent()) notifyAllListeners();
    return ps;
}
```

Is it possible to mock the chained call ?

Suppose that: `m.getParkingSpotDAO().getFreeSpot(category)` always returns a non-empty `Optional<ParkingSpot>`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where does the DAO get `m` from? Mock that.

Comment: @BoristheSpider 'm' represents the IDAOManager.